# How to scrape metrics from bitnami/mariadb helm deployment with kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, mariadb, bitnami, mariadb-10.5

I am using bitnami/mariadb helm chart deployments. I tried to enable the metrics and servicemonitor like below in the primary and secondary section in values.yaml file. And I noticed that the sidecar container and servicemonitor are not creating.

```
    metrics:
      enabled: true
      image:
        registry: docker.io
        repository: bitnami/mysqld-exporter
        tag: 0.14.0-debian-11-r37
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
        prometheus.io/port: '9104'
      serviceMonitor:
        enabled: true
        interval: 30s
        selector:
          release: prometheus
```

I have enabled the metrics in other bitnami apps like above. But I am not sure why it is not working here.

```
K8s version: 1.21
MariaDB app version: 10.5.11-debian-10-r25
```

Answer (score 0):

- consider creating the mysql-exporter in a sepreate pod: [link](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus-mysql-exporter)
- create a new user in the mysql pod, exporter for exemple and grant him the needed privileges

  ```
   CREATE USER 'exporter'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   GRANT PROCESS, REPLICATION CLIENT, SELECT ON *.* TO 'exporter'@'%';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  ```

this may differ depending on the sql version, after that pass the host/user/pass/port to the values in mysql-exporter so the exporter pod can connect to mysql pod, after doing that your prometheus server should be able to scrape data through the mysql-exporter pod.